# generate a notification near a location

Tags: android, location

I am trying to build a code which starts a notification when a user comes near to a location. I googled regarding the topic but was unable to find solution.I am using the following code but it is not working.

The below code is of my Location class whose inner class is MyLocationListener which  implements LocationListener

`  @Override
      public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
      {
          CharSequence from = "AlarmManager - Time's up!";
            CharSequence message = "This is your alert";

```
    loc.getLatitude();
    loc.getLongitude();

    String Text = "My current location is: " +
    "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() +
    "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();
    float radius = 500; //Distance in meters

      Location location1 = new Location("GPS");
      location1.setLatitude(loc.getLatitude());
      location1.setLongitude(location1.getLongitude());

      Location location2 = new Location("GPS");
      location2.setLatitude(22.727739);
      location2.setLongitude(75.886074);

      Float distance = location1.distanceTo(location2);
      distance = Math.abs(distance);
       if(distance < radius)
        {
            Log.d("sdsd", "task location");         
            notMan = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Click here for details", System.currentTimeMillis());

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Location_Gps.this,Location_Gps.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Location_Gps.this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

         n.setLatestEventInfo(Location_Gps.this, from,message, pendingIntent);
           notMan.notify(10001, n);

        }

    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Any help regarding the topic is appreciated.

Comment: does this run inside a Service?

Comment: no it is not running inside service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to build a code which starts a notification when a user comes near to a location.

Use `LocationListener` and `addProximityAlert()`.